# Persistent the authenticate user on main and the subdomains in the Laravel | Session | subdomains

Tags: php, laravel

Yes, I know it looks like an old question but still unclear.

I have two different Laravel applications and both have their **separate tables**. On my local system, I put both of them as subdomain domain(virtual host). Both of them are working fine.

What I want is that whenever a user logged in to either of the subdomains then the user should automatically be authenticated to another subdomain. So I don't need to login into my subdomain separately or again and again.

Some people suggest the following solution.

- use the identical setup for app key, session.php, database, and use the database as a driver for the session.
- use a third domain as the main domain(or subdomain like auth.example.com) and implement SSO with Laravel.
- use passport and create the main domain for the oAuth server to provide tokens.
- use Redis or Memcached as a session driver to persistent user authentication.
- prefix the table(for second app) with some specific string(i.e app_2) and use single database(i.e database merge)

Real use case:-

- One Laravel application handle all banking related feature so the subdomain will be banking.example.com
- One Laravel application handle all accounting related feature so the subdomain will be accounting.example.com

I am a little bit confused now. Currently, both application is built using blade template engine for now but in future, the frontend may be in React or Angular. As of now, I can go with the Laravel Blade template engine.

Can someone help me with how can I achieve a single login system and persistent user login and also sync user information across main and subdomains in **Laravel fashion**?